# Arranging a column vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a function `ABC(...)`, it returns a column vector, `[1 1 1]'` (apostrophe shows transpose).

When the function is called again it returns `[0 0 0 2 2 2]'`. Now I would like to combine these two outputs to get `[1 1 1 2 2 2]'`.

If I call the 3rd time, output is 9x1 e.g.,
`[0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3]'`, whereas I want `[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
outall=[];
for i=1:n
   out =ABC();
   ouall=[outall out(end-3:end)];
end
```